# Is there a well-tested Ender 3 printer profile for PrusaSlicer available for download?

Tags: creality-ender-3, slic3r, prusaslicer

I am very comfortable with using PrusaSlicer and having a hard time adapting Cura.

Is there any downloadable well-tested PrusaSlicer profile for some of the Creality printers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open PrusaSlicer, go to Configuration -> Configuration wizard, then go to page named "Other Vendors", tick the checkbox next to the name "Creality", then click "Next" at the bottom right of the window. A page with a handful of Creality printers should appear including Ender 3. Tick the checkbox under Creality Ender 3. Then click "Finish" at the bottom right. The profile should appear in the selection.

It imports various print settings (from 0.3 mm to 0.08 mm I believe) as well as some basic material presets. You can import more materials by just going to the "Filaments" page in the Configuration wizard and ticking the desired options.

The profiles are tested by PrusaResearch themselves I believe and I think they are based on other profiles found online with some tweaks and adjustments to better fit to PrusaSlicer.

I am using PrusaSlicer 2.3.0

Here is an image, what it should look like. Your colors might be different, I asume you are using Windows, wheras I am using Linux Mint.

[image: PrusaSlicer Creality printer selection screen]